# How to get SOAPHandler handleFault method to distinguish request and response

Tags: soap, jax-ws, soapfault, soaphandler

I am trying to use `SOAPHandler` to intercept the service call and I need to distinguish between `request` and `response` inside the `handleFault` method. The problem is that when either request or response is invalid and the `handleFault` method is called, I have no way of knowing which one it is. the `MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY` does not help, it is `true` in both cases when it comes to `handleFault`

Comment: I'm trying to get this working myself and I've only seen handleFault called on the response xml. That would explain why MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY is always true. The request seems to call handleMessage whether there's an error or not, I guess it doesn't know yet. Then if everything was ok I get another handleMessage, otherwise a handleFault.

Comment: @BenThurley yes, I had to use interceptors to solve my problem.